# MySQL Access denied for user 'user'@'some ip' with 'wildcard'

Tags: mysql

I'm using a MySql in a docker environment, and I created a user:

```sql
CREATE USER 'some_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_password';
GRANT ALL ON some_database.* TO 'some_user'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

When I tried to connect, I got the following error message:

```
Access denied for user 'some_user'@'172.23.0.3' (using password: YES)
```

Then I created a new user with the specific IP:

```sql
CREATE USER 'some_user'@'172.23.0.3' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_password';
GRANT ALL ON some_database.* TO 'some_user'@'172.23.0.3';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And everything went fine. So my question is:

**Shouldn't the wildcard in 'some_user'@'%' cover all IP addresses, including 'some_user'@'172.23.0.3'?**

**Why 'some_user'@'%' denied access to 'some_user'@'172.23.0.3'?**

I'm using mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.39, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: This is a good question that I've always wondered myself.  That said, I think this might be more of a question for dba stackexchange as it's not really a programming question.

Comment: (#1) Does `skip_name_resolve` is OFF? try to enable and check does the user is logged in successfully in this case. (#2) Try to specify a subnet (for example, `'some_user'@'172.23.0.%'`) - does the user is logged in successfully in this case?

Comment: Are you using mysql or mariadb container (SO tags and language are causing ambiguity)? I couldn't [reproduce your error](https://pastebin.com/Vnj9xWgN). `skip-name-resolve=1` is the default on both mysql and mariadb containers. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` aren't needed with `GRANT` /`CREATE USER` or any standard user modification.